# Meteor Facebook Messenger Bot webhook

Tags: javascript, facebook, meteor, bots, facebook-messenger

I'm trying to build a Facebook Messenger bot with Meteor. Setup includes looking for the Verify Token and respond with the challenge sent in the verification GET request. In Facebook's (non-Meteor) sample app, the following code is used:

```
app.get('/webhook', function(req, res) {
  if (req.query['hub.mode'] === 'subscribe' &amp;&amp;
      req.query['hub.verify_token'] === VALIDATION_TOKEN) {
    console.log("Validating webhook");
    res.status(200).send(req.query['hub.challenge']);
  } else {
    console.error("Failed validation. Make sure the validation tokens match.");
    res.sendStatus(403);          
  }  
});
```

When I try to achieve the same functionality using the following (Meteor) code, I receive the error below.

```
var bodyParser = Meteor.npmRequire( 'body-parser');

// Add two middleware calls. The first attempting to parse the request body as
// JSON data and the second as URL encoded data.
Picker.middleware( bodyParser.json() );
Picker.middleware( bodyParser.urlencoded( { extended: false } ) );

// ------------------------------------------------------------
// HANDLE THE INITIAL HANDSHAKE WITH FACEBOOK VIA A GET REQUEST
// ------------------------------------------------------------
var getRoutes = Picker.filter(function(req, res) {
  // you can write any logic you want.
  // but this callback does not run inside a fiber
  // at the end, you must return either true or false
  return req.method == "GET";
});

getRoutes.route('/webhook', function(params, req, res, next) {
  if (params.query['hub.verify_token'] === '78750') {
        console.log(params.query['hub.verify_token']);
        // res.end();
        res.end(params.query['hub.challenge']);
  }
}); // end getRoutes
```

Error:

```
The URL couldn't be validated. Response does not match challenge, expected value = '1127215706', received='<!DOCTYPE html> <htm...
```

Perhaps this issue is due to it being run on the client rather than the server? If so, where should I put this code in order for it to be run on the server?

In addition, my browser console has the following error 12 times:

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://pfbe.meteorapp.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure font 'http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/inconsolata/v5/BjAYBlHtW3CJxDcjzrnZCIbN6UDyHWBl620a-IRfuBk.woff'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

What can I do to fix this problem?

Comment: What do you mean by _“it being run on the client rather than the server”_? Facebook sends the request, so it _is_ the client here, and your _server_ is the one it is send to. // `received='<!DOCTYPE html> …` is pretty obvious - your endpoint returns a complete HTML document (whether it’s a default template, or perhaps an error document, can not be told from that snippet), and not just the challenge value as it is supposed to.

Comment: did you fixed ? or found a solution  ?

Answer (score 0):

Use Restivus
-You need to respond in the body with challenge and return it as a parsedInt